# How to run multiple tasks and return the result once the first task returned true

Tags: c#, task

How to write a method that runs some tasks asynchronously, checks the results from given tasks and once a task returned `true`, the method must stop executing and return the result.

Let say we got this function:

```
private static async Task<bool> DummyFunction()
{
    Random rand = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
    Thread.Sleep(rand.Next(1000, 10000));
    return await Task.FromResult(rand.Next(100) % 2 == 0);
}
```

And the following one will call `DummyFunction`

```
private async Task<bool> RunDummy()
{
    List<Task<bool>> tasks = new List<Task<bool>> { DummyFunction(), DummyFunction(), DummyFunction() };
    while (tasks.Any())
    {
        Task<bool> currentTask = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);
        if (await currentTask)
        {
            // do something ..., raise an event, call another method or whatever
            // or simply just return
            return true;
        }
        tasks.Remove(currentTask);
    }
    return false;
}
```

I found the code of `RunDummy` here somewhere on stackoverflow. but it rather runs synchronously. I tried to debug it and I noticed that it waits for every task to complete before it starts the next one.

My question is, how to run all tasks in parallel and stop executing at the very first method that returns `true`?

Comment: First, don't use the blocking `Thread.Sleep()`in an async method; use the non-blocking `await Task.Delay()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Task.WhenAny`. Your problem is not `RunDummy`.

The reason `RunDummy` waits for all tasks to complete is that `DummyFunction` is not really async. The line `Thread.Sleep(rand.Next(1000, 10000));` actually suspends the thread. See `Thread.Sleep` [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.sleep?view=netframework-4.7.2) - 'Suspends the current thread for the specified number of milliseconds'.

To make `DummyFunction` async, use `await Task.Delay(1000)`.

One more thing - the line `await Task.FromResult(rand.Next(100) % 2 == 0)` is also not async. `Task.FromResult` creates a finished `Task` and awaiting a finished task returns the value synchronously.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Tank you!